# Why is my array not behaving as expected?

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a months
months=([11]=D [7]=A [0]=J F M A M J J S O N)

echo There are ${#months[@]} months in a year. They are:
echo ${months[@]}
```

I am learning Bash. I was experimenting with arrays (after having read about them in the Bash manual), and I wanted to experiment with the out-of-order assignment.

When I run my code, 'There are 11 months in a year' is outputted, followed by 'J F M A M J J S O N D'.

The eight element - 'A' seems to be not getting stored in the array, and it is not being outputted.

Why might this be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
months=([11]=D [7]=A [0]=J F M A M J J S O N)
```

This assings D to index 11, A to index 7, J to index 0, F to index 1, M to index 2, A to index 3, M to index 4, J to indices 5 and 6, S to index 7 - **overwriting the previously stored A**!

If you want to store the whole string as a single element, quote it.

```
months=([11]=D [7]=A [0]='J F M A M J J S O N')
```

If you want the eighth element to be changed from A to S, put the `[7]=A` after the assignement to `[0]=J F M...`.